# Print 1 to 100 using 10 threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to muti-threading and I got a question to print 1 to 100 using 10 threads in Java with below constrain.

1. Thread `t1` should print:

   > 1, 11, 21, 31, ... 91

   `t2` should print:

   > 2, 12, 22, 32, ... 92

   likewise

   `t10` should print:

   > 10, 20, 30, ... 100
2. The final output should be

   > 1 2 3 .. 100

I have tried it, but it is throwing the following exception in all 10 threads:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at thread.run(MyThread.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

```
public class MyThread {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thread.setSequence();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new thread(i));
            t.setName(i + "");
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

class thread implements Runnable {
    private static HashMap< String, String> sequence = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static final Object lock = new Object();
    public static String turn = "1"; 
    private int startValue = 0;
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public thread(int startValue){
        this.startValue = startValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!counter.equals(10)){
            synchronized (lock) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals(turn)){  
                    System.out.print(startValue + " ");
                    startValue += 10;
                    counter.incrementAndGet();
                    turn = getNextTurn(turn);
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{                       
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setSequence(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            if (i == 10)
                sequence.put(i + "", 1 + "");
            else
                sequence.put(i + "", (i + 1) + "");
    }

    public static String getNextTurn(String currentTurn){
        return sequence.get(currentTurn);
    }
}
```

Comment: When using threads it is impossible to know in what order they will actually be run. So technically no matter what they print out the order can't be predicted.

Comment: If it's throwing some exception, fix your code so the exception isn't thrown.

Comment: maybe post the exception so we can see where the problem is

Comment: @yitzih : The questioner clearly mentioned we need to print it in the order. I have tried many ways but couldn't solve it.

Comment: @CodeCat : throwing IllegalMonitorStateException for all the 10 threads. please find below snippet 

Exception in thread "6" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
 at thread.run(MyThread.java:58)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Though this is not what threads are meant for still I have provided a generic solution that will work for n threads.

Comment: Why is it that the first thing everyone tries to do with threads is to totally defeat the entire point of using threads in the first place?

Comment: @Vivek You are getting that exception because you are using mutex as "lock" and calling wait() and notifyAll() using "this"

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way would be to have a volatile variable from which each thread reads in and update according to its turn, otherwise it just waits until his turn. When `counter` is equals to `100` you stop all threads to run by breaking the outer loop.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final int LIMIT = 20;
    private static volatile int counter = 0;
    private int id;

    public MyRunnable(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        outer:
        while(counter < LIMIT) {
            while (counter % NB_THREADS != id) {
                if(counter == LIMIT) break outer;
            }
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " printed " + counter);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Given a LIMIT of 20 and 10 threads, it outputs:

```
Thread 0 printed 0
Thread 1 printed 1
Thread 2 printed 2
Thread 3 printed 3
Thread 4 printed 4
Thread 5 printed 5
Thread 6 printed 6
Thread 7 printed 7
Thread 8 printed 8
Thread 9 printed 9
Thread 0 printed 10
Thread 1 printed 11
Thread 2 printed 12
Thread 3 printed 13
Thread 4 printed 14
Thread 5 printed 15
Thread 6 printed 16
Thread 7 printed 17
Thread 8 printed 18
Thread 9 printed 19
```

Of course, this is a very bad usage of multithreading because each thread waits its turn to print and increment the counter.

Multithreading works well when threads can work independently of another for relatively long time's window, and then may occasionally meet up to compare or combine their results if needed.

For example in the fork-join model, each thread does its task independently then their results are merged to produce the final outcome, such as in a merge sort for example. But this assume that the task can be easily parallelizable into independant subtasks, which is not the case here because your final output should be consecutive numbers.

So here a simple loop would be largely more efficient, but I can understand it's for learning purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for the problem.The current thread acquire the lock and we decide if the thread is eligible to execute (printing the number here). If so perform the operation and notify all threads that they can try now. Else wait till its notified by other threads.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

//define the Total No.Of Threads needed
public static final int TOTAL_THREADS = 10;

public final static Object obj = new Object();

int threadNo;   
static volatile int counter = 1;

public MyThread(int threadNo){
    this.threadNo= threadNo;
}

@Override
public void run(){

    //in a synchronized block to acquire lock
    synchronized (obj) {

        while(counter<=100){

            /*
             * counter==threadNo => To print the initial numbers till TOTAL_THREADS
             * counter%TOTAL_THREADS == threadNo => e.g 11%10 = 1 -> 1 will print this, 12%10 = 2 ..
             * (counter%TOTAL_THREADS == 0) && (TOTAL_THREADS == threadNo) => 10%10 will be 0, 
             *              and this must be printed by 10 th thread only, ie the highest thread.
             */
            if(counter == threadNo || (counter%TOTAL_THREADS == threadNo) ||
                    ((counter%TOTAL_THREADS == 0) && (TOTAL_THREADS == threadNo))){

                //Display the output as desired
                System.out.println(this.threadNo+" printing"+" "+counter++);

                //notify
                obj.notifyAll();
            }else{

                //current thread not eligible for printing the current counter value, so wait till its notified
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main (String args[]) {

    /*
     * Creating as many threads as needed.
     */
    for(int i = 1; i<=TOTAL_THREADS;i++){
        MyThread th = new MyThread(i);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

}

The output will be
 
1 printing 1,
2 printing 2,
3 printing 3,
4 printing 4,
5 printing 5,
6 printing 6,
7 printing 7,
8 printing 8,
9 printing 9,
10 printing 10,
1 printing 11,
2 printing 12,
3 printing 13,
4 printing 14,
...
7 printing 97,
8 printing 98,
9 printing 99,
10 printing 100

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps =) Took me an hour to do it.

```
package com.xxxx.simpleapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TenThreads {

    public int currentTaskValue = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TenThreads monitor = new TenThreads();
        List<ModThread> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ModThread modThread = new ModThread(i, monitor);
            list.add(modThread);
        }
        for (ModThread a : list) {
            a.start();
        }
    }

}

class ModThread extends Thread {
    private int modValue;
    private TenThreads monitor;

    public ModThread(int modValue, TenThreads monitor) {
        this.modValue = modValue;
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    while (monitor.currentTaskValue % 10 != modValue) {
                        monitor.wait();
                    }

                    if (monitor.currentTaskValue == 101) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "
                            + monitor.currentTaskValue + " ,");
                    monitor.currentTaskValue = monitor.currentTaskValue + 1;
                    monitor.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Thread-1 : 1 ,
Thread-2 : 2 ,
Thread-3 : 3 ,
Thread-4 : 4 ,
Thread-5 : 5 ,
Thread-6 : 6 ,
Thread-7 : 7 ,
Thread-8 : 8 ,
Thread-9 : 9 ,
......
.....
...
Thread-4 : 94 ,
Thread-5 : 95 ,
Thread-6 : 96 ,
Thread-7 : 97 ,
Thread-8 : 98 ,
Thread-9 : 99 ,
Thread-0 : 100 ,
```

Documentation are intentionally left out for you to figure it out, there are minor bugs too!

Comment: it does not end the loop,it goes in waiting state. you also need to add a condition inside the wait() loop.
' if (monitor.currentTaskValue == 101) {
                        break;
                    }'

Answer (score 2):

Error is thrown due to calling of `wait` not on proper object. `wait()` should be called on object on which lock is acquired, the one implied by `synchronized` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Well I do not have the code...but the perspective seems to be
that there are 100 tasks to be executed each of incrementing
a count by 1.
So there could be a ThreadPool of say 10 threads and these
threads are incrementing the shared count value...
Only point to consider is that the Thread pools worker threads
have to sequentially execute their tasks one after the other
and the thread sequence for the 10 have to be maintained...

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to solve this is use below state in runnable class

```
 private final int index;
 private final AtomicInteger atomicInteger;
 private final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
```

index - is responsible for conditional verification i.e., which number this thread should print.
atomicInteger - shared across all threads for current number.
Cyclic barrier - makes all threads to wait unit a every thread completes a cycle/iteration.

Code sample:

```
public class PrintSequence {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
        final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(10, ()-> {
            System.out.println("a cycle done");
        });

        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9)
                .boxed()
                .map(i -> new PrintSequenceTask(i, atomicInteger, cyclicBarrier))
                .map(p -> executorService.submit(p))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}


class PrintSequenceTask implements Runnable {
    private final int index;
    private final AtomicInteger atomicInteger;
    private final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    PrintSequenceTask(int index, AtomicInteger atomicInteger, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.index = index;
        this.atomicInteger = atomicInteger;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=1; i<10;i++){
            while (((atomicInteger.get()-index-1)%10 != 0)){}
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+(atomicInteger.get()));
            atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
            await();
        }
    }

    public void await(){
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BigSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigPrintNum p = new BigPrintNum();
        int max = 20;
        int no_threads = 11;
        for(int i=0;i<no_threads;i++){
            boolean b[] = new boolean[no_threads];
            b[i] = true;
            Thread t = new Thread(new BigPrint(p, max, b,no_threads));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
class BigPrint implements Runnable {

    int num=0;
    BigPrintNum p;
    int max;
    int no_threads;
    boolean b[];
    public BigPrint(BigPrintNum p,int max,boolean b[],int no_threads){
        this.p = p;
        this.max = max;
        this.b = b;
        this.no_threads = no_threads;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int n = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<no_threads;i++){
            if(b[i] == true){
                n = i;
                num = i;
            }
        }
        while(num<=max){
            p.print(num, n, no_threads);
            num += no_threads;
        }
    }   
}
class BigPrintNum {
    int turn = 0;
    public synchronized void print(int n,int i,int no_threads){
        while(this.turn != i){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i + "th seq = " + n);
        this.turn = (i+1)%no_threads;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Its a generic one, where we can use any number of threads and use any max value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreadSequence 
{

    public static int totalThread;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        MyLock myLock = new MyLock();
        totalThread = 10;

        for(int i=1;i<=totalThread;i++)
        {
            MyThread myThread = new MyThread(i,myLock);
            myThread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

```
class MyLock
{

    public int counter = 0;

}
```

MyThread Class

```
class MyThread extends Thread{

    public MyLock lock;
    public int no;
    public MyThread(int no,MyLock lock)
    {
        super("My Thread No "+no);
        this.no = no;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run()
    {

        synchronized (lock) 
        {

            while(true)
            {

                while(lock.counter%ThreadSequence.totalThread !=(this.no-1))
                {

                    try 
                    {

                        if(lock.counter > 99)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        lock.wait();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(lock.counter > 99)
                {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Current Thread "+Thread.currentThread().currentThread()+" --- Current Count "+(lock.counter+1));
                lock.counter = lock.counter +1 ;
                lock.notifyAll();   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

print 1 to 100 number alternatively by each thread similar way you can print for 10 threads- m1 and m2 like
m1-1
m2-2
m3-3
m4-4

```
public class MultiThread extends Thread {
    static volatile int  num=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiThread m1= new MultiThread();
        MultiThread m2= new MultiThread();
        m1.setName("m1");
        m1.setPriority(5);
        m2.setName("m2");
        m2.setPriority(5);
        m1.start();
        m2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(num<100) {
            num +=1;
            print();
        }

    }

    private void print(){
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(currentThread().getName()+" "+ num);
            try {
                currentThread().wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple thing to do is to hold common resource for all of them.
Hold a List and every thread will insert into the list, in the end you can sort and print.. 
If you want them to do it on your order it won't be very effective because you won't need 10 threads to do it..

This way it will be faster and will use 10 threads to do some work, but when everyone finish you still need to do some work

Answer (score -1):

```
public class PrintNumbersbyThreads implements Runnable {
    private int i;

    public PrintNumbersbyThreads(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintNumbersbyThreads p = new PrintNumbersbyThreads(1);
        PrintNumbersbyThreads p2 = new PrintNumbersbyThreads(2);
        PrintNumbersbyThreads p3 = new PrintNumbersbyThreads(3);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p2, "t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(p3, "t3");
        t1.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.start();
            t2.join();
            t3.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("\n" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " prints  ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            i = i + 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Written sample code 3 Threads and the output is

`t1` prints:

> 1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91

`t2` prints:

> 2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92

`t3` prints:

> 3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93

Hope this is what you are Looking for?

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is NOT what he was looking for!  He ain't going to learn by just copying your solution.

Comment: I like this solution much better!

Comment: @user4127 Except that this is not what the OP wants. He wants the numbers to be outputted consecutively. Here `t2` will wait for `t1` to finish and same applies for `t3` with `t2`.

Answer (score -1):

I have written one generic code which will take the number till where you want to print and the number of threads to be used.

```
public class ThreadedPrinting {
    private Object locks[];

    private static class Printer extends Thread {
        int curVal;
        int endVal;
        Object myLock;
        Object nextLock;
        int step;

        public Printer(int startFrom, int endVal, int step, Object myLock, Object nextLock){
            this.curVal = startFrom;
            this.endVal = endVal;
            this.step = step;
            this.myLock = myLock;
            this.nextLock = nextLock;
            this.step = step;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(myLock) {
                while (curVal <= endVal) {
                    try {
                        myLock.wait();
                        System.out.println(curVal);
                        curVal += step;
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                    synchronized(nextLock) {
                        nextLock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
            synchronized(nextLock) {
                nextLock.notify(); /// this ensures all worker threads exiting at the end
            }
        }
    } // Printer

    public ThreadedPrinting(int maxNum, int threads) {
        locks = new Object[threads];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < threads; ++i) locks[i] = new Object();
        for(i = 0; i < threads -1 ; ++i) {
            Printer curPrinter = new Printer(i, maxNum, threads, locks[i], locks[i+1]);
            curPrinter.start();
        }
        Printer lastPrinter = new Printer(i, maxNum, threads, locks[threads - 1], locks[0]);
        lastPrinter.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        synchronized (locks[0]) {
            locks[0].notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadedPrinting printer = new ThreadedPrinting(1000,7);
        printer.start();
    }
}
```

The same problem can be solved by usign Phaser as well but the order is not restrictive but will be in round-robin fashion. I have provided the solution for similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314852/running-threads-in-round-robin-fashion-in-java/29934870#29934870).

Comment: Though I don't mind -1 vote but please at least provide the reason for that. This code works fine and I want to know why was it down voted.

Comment: add this in your sysout  System.out.println(curVal +"The thread name is"+Printer.currentThread());