# What's the round robin schedulers used in practice

Tags: python, multithreading, jvm, scheduler, ghc

as part of my project, I need to work on a **round robin thread scheduler**, which should better be a practical and useful scheduler, not a toy. However I find difficult to find one.

- I do know that `GHC` has a user-level threading support with a round-robin scheduler. But I'm not good with Haskell :(
- Google told me that both JVM and Python VM use host OS's scheduler, which means technically they don't support user-space threading.

Am I right about JVM and Python here? Do you guys have any proposal for such kind of scheduler?

Comment: Nginx load balancer?

Comment: Python threads are indeed native threads: Python does not have its own scheduler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we use multi-thread in round robin manner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715366/how-can-we-use-multi-thread-in-round-robin-manner)